# Помогите упростить код и избавиться от двойного For

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Вот часть кода. После первого `print (vid_avto)` результат таков - `[('Мар',), ('Тро',), ('Авт',)]`. Приходится в двойном цикле `for` пробежаться по списку и создать новый список. После второго `print(list_vid_avto)` результат уже тот что мне надо - `['Мар', 'Тро', 'Авт']`. Мне очень не нравится это двойной `for`. Подскажите есть ли другая возможность добиться желаемого результата и упростить сам код. Учусь…

```
def sql_database_transport():
try:
    sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect('Bus_stop.db')
    cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
    sql_select = f"SELECT autotransport.vid_avto FROM autotransport"
    vid_avto = cursor.execute(sql_select).fetchall()
    print (vid_avto)
    list_vid_avto = []
    for vid_a in vid_avto:
        for vd in vid_a:
            list_vid_avto.append(vd)
    print(list_vid_avto)
    return list_vid_avto
```

Comment: Самое простое - обращаться по индексу. Также можно использовать sqlite3.Row https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-create-and-use-row-factories. Тогда можно будет обращаться и по ключу, чье значение будет название колонки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, list_vid_avto должен содержать нулевые элементы кортежей, входящих в vid_avto, тогда:

```
def sql_database_transport():
    try:
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect('Bus_stop.db')
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        sql_select = f"SELECT autotransport.vid_avto FROM autotransport"
        vid_avto = cursor.execute(sql_select).fetchall()
        print (vid_avto)
        list_vid_avto = []
        for vid_a in vid_avto:
            list_vid_avto.append(vid_a[0])
        print(list_vid_avto)
        return list_vid_avto
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Код уменшился на одну строчку. Но все равно большое спасибо Dmitry Websmith. Как по мне выглядить лутче.